# Sandcastle's scbuild.ps1 takes so much time

Tags: powershell, sandcastle

I've executed the `scbuild.ps1` in this manner

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Sandcastle\ProductionTools
powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
cd <location of dll and xml docs>
scbuild -framework 2.0 -sources <comma separated dlls and xml doc> -BuildWebsite
```

however, it appears that `scbuild.ps1` creates xml doc for MS Core libs (System.*).

How can I prevent the additional step of building the xmldoc of ms.net core libraries?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [documentation on the scbuild.ps1 script](https://sandcastle.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Development/ProductionTools/scbuild.ps1) it appears the `-sources` parameter requires the xml doc.

> -Sources {files} -- comma separated list of files that should be added to the output, both assemblies and related comment files. To build, you must specify at least one assembly and comment file.

Comment: -sources refers list of dll and xmldoc that will serve as reference to create documentation